# xmllint to parse a html file

Tags: bash, macos, xpath, xmllint

I was trying to parse out text between specific tags on a mac in various html files.  I was looking for the first `<H1>` heading in the body. Example:

```
<BODY>
<H1>Dublin</H1>
```

Using regular expressions for this I believe is an anti pattern so I used xmllint and xpath instead.

```
xmllint --nowarning --xpath '/HTML/BODY/H1[0]'
```

Problem is some of the HTML files contain badly formed tags. So I get errors on the lines of

```
 parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: UL line 261 and LI
</LI>
```

Problem is I can't just do, `2>/dev/null` as then I loose those files altogether.  Is there any way, I can just use an XPath expression here and just say, relax if the XML isn't perfect, just give me the value between the first H1 headings?

Answer (score 13):

Try the `--html` option. Otherwise, `xmllint` parses your document as XML which is a lot stricter than HTML. Also note that XPath indices are 1-based and that HTML tags are converted to lowercase when parsing. The command

```
xmllint --html --xpath '/html/body/h1[1]' - <<EOF
<BODY>
<H1>Dublin</H1>
EOF
```

prints

```
<h1>Dublin</h1>
```

Comment: I get even more mismatches when I do that. Instead of ./myfile.html:131: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: UL line 127 and LI  I get HTML parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: ul and td

Comment: @MoreThanFive libxml2's HTML parser isn't very forgiving. The `--recover` option might help in addition to `--nowarning` which you already discovered.