# Parse XML from not well formed page using xpath

Tags: html, bash, xpath, xmlstarlet, xmllint

**Notice**:
While writing this question, I notice that there is a Github API that solves my problem without HTML parsing: https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest I decided to ask it anyway since I'm intested how to solve the described problem of parsing malformed HTML itself. So please *dont downvote* because there is a github API for it! We can replace github by any other page throwing validation errors.

I want to download the latest version of [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver). By fetching the redirection target of the latest tag, I'm on the releases page

```
curl $(curl -s "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest" --head | grep -i location | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\r//g') > /tmp/geckodriver.html
```

The first assets with `geckodriver-vx.xxx-linux64.tar.gz` is the required link. Since XML is schemantic, it should be parsed properly. [Different tools like `xmllint`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15461774/9428314) could parse it using [xpaths](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html). Since xpath is new for me, I tried a simple query on the header. But `xmllint` throws a lot of errors:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//div[@class=Header]' /tmp/geckodriver.html
/tmp/geckodriver.html:51: parser error : Specification mandate value for attribute data-pjax-transient
  <meta name="selected-link" value="repo_releases" data-pjax-transient>
                                                                      ^
/tmp/geckodriver.html:107: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 105 and head
  </head>
         ^
/tmp/geckodriver.html:145: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined
                Sign&nbsp;up
                          ^
/tmp/geckodriver.html:172: parser error : Entity 'rarr' not defined
es <span class="Bump-link-symbol float-right text-normal text-gray-light">&rarr;
...
```

There are a lot more. It seems that the github page is not properly well formed, as the specification requires it. I also tried `xmlstarlet`

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v -m '//div[@class=Header]' /tmp/geckodriver.html
```

but the result is similar.

Is it not possible to extract some data using those tools when the HTML is not well formed?

Comment: So its perfectly valid for `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` to throw errors on a malformed XML content.

Comment: But I don't get any output from the provided selector. I'd expect to get the selected HTML element and would require some _silent_ mode that doesn't print those bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1):

> `curl $(curl -s "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest" --head | grep -i location | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\r//g') > /tmp/geckodriver.html`

It may be simpler to [use `-L`, and have `curl` follow the redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474690/is-there-a-way-to-follow-redirects-with-command-line-curl):

```
curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest
```

Then, `xmllint` [accepts an `--html` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680061/xmllint-to-parse-a-html-file), to use an HTML parser:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@class=Header]'
```

However, this doesn't match anything on that page, so perhaps you want to base your XPath on something like:

```
'string((//a[span[contains(.,"linux")]])[1]/@href)'
```

Which yields:

```
/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux32.tar.gz
```